Calculating time of flight of GPS signal
I have read and watched a lot things about it. Some say GPS receivers can get time of flight with shifting local replice of PRN code. Some say it is for measuring time of arrival (which much more sense for me).
If it is first option how do receivers do this by shifting? Even receivers can calculate max 1ms of shifting (because length of PRN code) and when multiply it with speed of light it can get maximum 300km which is much more less than satellite altitude.
If it is second option and if you will say for calculating time of flight receivers must examine timestamp in the navigation message that has 6 sec period, I am going to ask that;
How can daily used GPS receivers calculate locations for every second even much less than?

Not sure this is a GIS   topic. The GPS Wikipedia page provides the sequence: PRN shift => TOA (in receiver clock reference). ToA & ToT gives Pseudoranges (ToF + clock difference). From there, 4 satellites give 3d position+clock difference resolution. 300km is the spatial PRN code length: receivers solve for locations within that range of the earth surface (except for specific space based applications )

You will also see from.the Wikipedia page that the Navigation message does will not change every 6 seconds. + Detailed navigation equations are given

@Kasper The real question is that: how receivers calculate time of flight for every second even much more less than? So, receivers just calculate distance to 300km? Is that range okay because of in the pseudorange formulas it will be proportional?

The pseudorange formula & the fact that the receiver will search for a solution near the earth surface will cope with the fact that 300km is shorter than the actual Sat to receiver distance.. First result of a Google search : https://inventeksys.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/GPS_Facts_Principles_of_GPS.pdf

Check submission for grammar and spelling. Also state a clear question and cut the unnecessary text (e.g., first paragraph)

@Fjedsen it wasn't unnecessary at all. Thanks
